# tie virtual pc to a user account on Windows 7

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

Is there a way that when you log in a user account, it automatically opens up the virtual machine? and then the user works inside the virtual pc? So even if they do something harmful to the computer, then it's all in Virtual PC?

OS: Windows 7
Virtual PC - Windows XP

(Please don't suggest Parental control as an alternative. I found it cumbersome to set up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shortcut to your virtual machine and put it in the Startup Program group of the user you wish to have the Virtual Machine configuration applied to.

You may want to customise the shortcut to appear full screen and automatically boot (You can do this by right-clicking the shortcut and editing the Target field):

**"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual PC\Virtual PC.exe" -pc "Windows XP" -launch -fullscreen**

A more complete reference to command-line options for Virtual PC is available online here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833142

In addition, you might want to go one further and disable Explorer from starting and using VirtualPC as the shell instead of starting the Windows Explorer. These instructions apply to Windows XP Embedded, but may well work with Windows 7, if you're considering experimentation:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576(v=winembedded.5).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx)

Comment: You should also tell the virtual pc to autologin the user. But `Right Alt-key + Enter` minimizes the guest machine, so it's really not very secure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, but that is bound to be more complicated than setting up "Parental control".

My suggestion is that you either do this:
["Windows 7 Guest Mode Creates Bomb-Proof Account"](http://lifehacker.com/5176876/windows-7-guest-mode-creates-bomb+proof-accounts)
or this:
["Kid-Proof Your PC with SteadyState"](http://lifehacker.com/397786/kid+proof-your-pc-with-steadystate)